# flex: Embedding assets from XML file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I want to create something like gallerea of images. All images are defined within an XML file. The XML file itself sits in the project directory and embedded this way:

```
[Embed(source="xml/data.xml")]
public var testXml:Class;
```

The file structure looks this way

```
<xml>
    <item>
        <title>A</title>
        <image>A.jpg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>B</title>
        <image>B.jpg</image>
    </item>
</xml>
```

I am reading the XML file within the application and parse it.

The question is: Is that possible to embed these images into the application at the compile time. (So the swf will be a complete alone standing application which doesn't make any web requests, etc)

Answer (score 1):

[This was already answered today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633048/is-it-possible-to-create-dinamic-embed-function)
Basically, embedding is done at compile-time and is not meant to be done at run-time.