# Actionsript : Is it possible to create a dynamic embed code with a string

Tags: actionscript, embed

```
public function PngInit(pngName:String):void
    {
        [Embed(source="../../lib/img/"+pngName+".png")]
        var Zozor:Class;
        Zozor.name = pngName;
        addChild([pngName]);
    }
```

This code returns me an Error : Invalid Metadata at the Embed line. How can I fix this ?
Btw, my function should be able to find a .png in my img folder from the string, and then directly add it to the scene. I am pretty new to Actionscript, so forgive my lack of skill. I am also french, so forgive my bad english ;).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create dynamic embed function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633048/is-it-possible-to-create-dynamic-embed-function)